# Rjags error: node inconsistent with parents works with one dataset but not the other

Tags: r, jags, rjags, r2jags

I have a jags model in R (version 4.3.0 (2023-04-21 ucrt)) using rjags (rjags_4-14).

The model runs without error for one dataset (named below: "works"). With a different dataset, which is the "works" dataset with additional observations (named below: "notworks"), I get the error:

> Error in jags.model(file = model.file, data = data, inits = inits, n.chains = n.chains,  :
> Error in node R[43]
> Node inconsistent with parents

I understand that something is wrong. I have looked at many other posts, including [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71174973/in-rjags-runjags-what-causes-the-node-inconsistent-with-parents-error-when-us), which also links a bunch of other posts that I've scoured. I am new to jags, and it seems that everyone's issue is unique for this error. Could someone help me understand what "R[43]" actually means in the code or model so that when I create new models I can pick this apart myself? Can you provide a solution so that the second dataset runs? Thank you.

```
Spred = seq(0, 10, 0.05)
jags_data = list(
  nyrs = nrow(dat), 
  Hobs = dat$EST.1.100m, 
  Sobs = dat$Redds.100m, 
  Spred = Spred, 
  nSpred = length(Spred),
  tauS = 1/0.3^2,
  tauH = 1/0.5^2
  )


jags_model = function() {
  # priors
  alpha ~ dunif(1, 20)
  beta ~ dunif(0,1)
  sigmaR ~ dunif(0,3)
  tauR <- 1/sigmaR^2


  Rmean[1] <- log(alpha)/beta 
  R[1] ~ dlnorm(log(Rmean[1]), tauR)
  

  for (y in 2:nyrs) {
    Rmean[y] <- alpha * S[y-1] * exp(-beta * S[y-1])  
    R[y] ~ dlnorm(log(Rmean[y]), tauR)               
  }
  

  for (y in 1:nyrs) {
    U[y] ~ dbeta(1,1)          
    H[y] <- R[y] * U[y]       
    S[y] <- R[y] * (1 - U[y])
  }
  

  for (y in 1:nyrs) {
    Sobs[y] ~ dlnorm(log(S[y]), tauS)
    Hobs[y] ~ dlnorm(log(H[y]), tauH)
  }
  

  Smsy <- log(alpha)/beta * (0.5 - 0.07 * log(alpha))
  MSY <- alpha * Smsy * exp(-beta * Smsy) - Smsy

  for (i in 1:nSpred) {

    Rpred[i] <- alpha * Spred[i] * exp(-beta * Spred[i])
    SY[i] <- Rpred[i] - Spred[i]
    

    p_meet[i,1] <- step(SY[i] - (0.7 * MSY))
    p_meet[i,2] <- step(SY[i] - (0.8 * MSY))
    p_meet[i,3] <- step(SY[i] - (0.9 * MSY))
  }
}

# write model to a text file
jags_file = "model.txt"
write_model(jags_model, jags_file)


jags_inits = function(nc) {
  inits = list()
  for (c in 1:nc) {
    inits[[c]] = list(
      alpha = runif(1, 4, 8),
      beta = runif(1, 0.1, 0.5),
      sigmaR = runif(1, 0.2, 0.5),
      U = with(jags_data, rbeta(nyrs, 100 * Hobs/(Hobs+Sobs), 100 * (1 - Hobs/(Hobs+Sobs)))),
      R = with(jags_data, rlnorm(nyrs, log(Hobs + Sobs), 0.1))
    )
  }
  return(inits)
}

jags_params = c(
  "alpha", "beta", "sigmaR",
  "R", "S", "H", "U", 
  "p_meet", "MSY", "Smsy", "Rpred")


jags_dims = c(
  ni = 50000,  
  nb = 20000, 
  nt = 10,    
  nc = 2     
)

with(as.list(jags_dims), ni/nt * nc)


post = jagsUI::jags.basic(
  data = jags_data,
  model.file = jags_file,
  inits = jags_inits(jags_dims["nc"]),
  parameters.to.save = jags_params,
  n.adapt = 1000,
  n.iter = sum(jags_dims[c("ni", "nb")]),
  n.thin = jags_dims["nt"],
  n.burnin = jags_dims["nb"],
  n.chains = jags_dims["nc"],
  parallel = F
)
```

Data that works:

```
dput(works)
structure(list(EST.1.100m = c(50.03436426, 29.6619718333333, 
21.3333333333333, 17.5644444466667, 10.9090909066667, 1.33333333333333, 
3.926589776, 9.74298464, 12.6666666666667, 25.6666666666667, 
18.73469388, 16.11965812, 28.6349206333333, 58.4074074066667, 
36.7659574466667, 30.1363636333333, 32.37777778, 10, 13.93939394, 
32.6210045666667, 46.7801418466667, 44.12658228, 36.9047619066667, 
37.5257731933333, 19.53488372, 23.8095238066667, 4.8, 1.10168078533333, 
12.6, 50.08695652, 7.33333333333333, 7.33333333333333, 15.05376344, 
29.7721519, 19.25, 25.2470588266667, 29.5909090933333, 21.09722222, 
26.57777778, 10.98039216, 30.68992248, 22.2189054733333, 24.9263157866667, 
16.4833333333333, 19.0188679266667, 37.5, 20.73429952, 39.79288026, 
20.1165048533333, 30.3003663, 21.81818182, 21.3918128666667, 
19.6756756733333, 20.6666666666667, 2.836471968, 13.0888888866667, 
12.6666666666667, 8.15514054, 10, 4.41666666666667, 6.96, 8.5106383, 
21.3333333333333, 32.4133333333333, 14.875, 10.7916666666667, 
8.08080808, 10.2702702733333, 25.14285714, 7.56989247333333, 
14.9787234066667, 15.44827586, 19.1020408133333, 7.55555555333333, 
7.33333333333333, 7.98039216, 18.60465116, 16.1333333333333, 
2.66666666666667, 6.66666666666667, 4.66666666666667, 5.33333333333333, 
24, 20.6666666666667, 30.4411764733333, 23.2962962933333, 63.05084746, 
20.6666666666667, 58.5347985333333, 49.18996416, 35.4430379733333, 
48.32982456, 57.1358024666667, 26.1333333333333, 59.9925925933333, 
77.0833333333333, 65.3195876266667, 62.58064516, 52.5821596266667, 
105, 32.3037974666667, 17.90804598, 25.31073446, 9.52, 24.92307692, 
9.33333333333333, 20.3333333333333, 13, 11, 27.90277778, 15.3333333333333, 
25.1700680266667, 14.31884058, 16.6666666666667, 16, 41.95767196, 
24.5333333333333, 13.8461538466667, 13.0666666666667, 15.3333333333333, 
11.3333333333333, 20.5050505066667, 18.75, 9.33333333333333, 
14.71264368, 83.8666666666667, 50.9390681, 27.2333333333333, 
50.30420712, 57.11442786, 75.8137254666667, 46.8841607533333, 
64.5882352933333, 3.401360544, 62.84126984, 12.4, 57.92063492, 
1.50617283933333, 57.7073170733333, 5.33333333333333, 20.5333333333333, 
25.7627118666667, 23.4347826066667, 19.7727272733333, 16.1, 27.1515151533333, 
45.6038647333333, 3.33333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 5.33333333333333, 
6.588235294, 33.25170068, 32.3076923066667, 3.33333333333333, 
4.24036956666667, 6, 5.30975916533333, 9.62962962666667, 4.66666666666667, 
36.8609271533333, 25.3255813933333, 30.0487804866667, 4.925925926, 
4.48697225266667, 2.66666666666667, 10, 8.04597701333333, 11.3333333333333, 
10, 12, 2.78260869533333, 2.66666666666667, 8.28571428666667, 
21.2105263133333, 31.1538461533333, 13.2173913066667, 7.43589743333333, 
14.6666666666667, 15.3333333333333, 20.8333333333333, 25.1234567933333, 
25.81560284, 15.3333333333333, 19.54285714, 10.7466666666667, 
9.33333333333333, 8, 16, 19.9689922466667, 10, 15.12, 2.19047619066667, 
12.0888888866667, 19.3333333333333, 2.823529412, 13.3333333333333, 
9.16594128, 19.8333333333333, 22.6285714266667, 10.9090909066667, 
16.2095238066667, 29.2307692333333, 15.5833333333333, 14.98245614, 
40.18079096, 36.8547008533333, 31.9444444466667, 9.89333333333333, 
4.336925954, 69.5338346, 13.87755102, 14.9333333333333, 26.08955224, 
47.37078652, 22.8194444466667, 25.5163398666667, 3.43434343466667, 
11.6097561, 15.5555555533333, 10.4347826066667, 18.12121212, 
17.3333333333333, 16.7272727266667, 51.24919094, 19.1489361733333, 
27.9545454533333, 9.82222222, 13.5714285733333, 9.62962962666667, 
6.02898550733333), Redds.100m = c(0.328497125650151, 0.342184505885574, 
0.437996167533534, 0.218998083766767, 0.0273747604708459, 0.150561182589652, 
0.191623323295921, 0.0821242814125376, 0.177935943060498, 0.410621407062688, 
0.46537092800438, 0.437996167533534, 0.301122365179305, 0.164248562825075, 
0.164248562825075, 0.150561182589652, 0.205310703531344, 0.506433068710649, 
0.547495209416918, 0.287434984943882, 0.314809745414728, 0.109499041883384, 
0.123186422118806, 0.0821242814125376, 0.109499041883384, 0.287434984943882, 
0.0547495209416918, 0.218998083766767, 0.218998083766767, 0.0547495209416918, 
0.191623323295921, 0.396934026827265, 3.3997441052824, 2.48583439956132, 
3.56424785231219, 2.86967647596417, 3.3997441052824, 4.73405227563517, 
3.01590202887955, 2.77828550539207, 3.07073661122281, 2.90623286419302, 
3.25351855236703, 3.41802229939682, 3.19868397002376, 2.44927801133248, 
2.12027051727289, 1.66331566441236, 1.55364649972583, 1.53536830561141, 
1.37086455858161, 1.40742094681046, 0.73112776457686, 0.511789435203802, 
0.639736794004752, 0.603180405775909, 0.44018643190057, 0.349559813568099, 
0.401346452615225, 0.854479544277576, 0.414293112377007, 1.10046607975142, 
0.919212843086484, 0.595546349041947, 1.17814603832211, 0.699119627136199, 
1.03573278094252, 0.867426204039358, 0.841532884515795, 0.80269290523045, 
0.97099948213361, 0.893319523562921, 0.932159502848265, 0.737959606421543, 
0.168306576903159, 0.349559813568099, 0.245986535473848, 0.479026411185914, 
0.168306576903159, 0.297773174520974, 0.323666494044537, 0.103573278094252, 
0.257653834495302, 0.257653834495302, 0.121248863291907, 0.242497726583813, 
0.409214913610185, 0.36374658987572, 0.621400424371022, 0.500151561079115, 
0.682024856016975, 0.409214913610185, 0.560775992725068, 0.439527129433162, 
0.575932100636557, 0.36374658987572, 0.469839345256138, 0.424371021521673, 
0.212185510760837, 0.45468323734465, 0.670933113129645, 0.867052023121387, 
1.75474814203138, 1.96118909991742, 1.45540875309661, 1.3934764657308, 
1.36251032204789, 1.05284888521883, 0.949628406275805, 1.20767960363336, 
0.774153592072667, 1.4037985136251, 1.4037985136251, 0.949628406275805, 
1.03220478943022, 0.609000825763832, 0.815441783649876, 0.433526011560694, 
0.990916597853014, 1.20767960363336, 0.712221304706854, 0.639966969446738, 
0.660611065235343, 0.268373245251858, 0.309661436829067, 2.33064014916097, 
2.67246737103791, 2.08203853325047, 3.07644499689248, 1.61591050341827, 
1.52268489745183, 1.55376009944065, 1.95773772529521, 0.74580484773151, 
1.39838408949658, 0.52827843380982, 0.435052827843381, 0.652579241765072, 
0.870105655686762, 0.279676817899316, 1.2119328775637, 1.08763206960845, 
0.932256059664388, 1.55376009944065, 1.24300807955252, 0.932256059664388, 
0.683654443753884, 0.310752019888129, 0.341827221876942, 0.652579241765072, 
1.33623368551896, 1.6780609073959, 1.61591050341827, 1.6780609073959, 
1.95773772529521, 0.994406463642014, 1.24300807955252, 1.2119328775637, 
0.652579241765072, 0.510783200908059, 0.638479001135074, 0.297956867196368, 
0.312145289443814, 0.368898978433598, 0.482406356413167, 0.411464245175936, 
0.297956867196368, 0.297956867196368, 0.227014755959137, 0.439841089670829, 
0.411464245175936, 0.624290578887628, 0.482406356413167, 0.454029511918275, 
0.92485549132948, 0.130057803468208, 0.968208092485549, 2.03757225433526, 
0.852601156069364, 1.64739884393064, 1.76300578034682, 1.22832369942197, 
1.35838150289017, 1.48843930635838, 1.63294797687861, 1.77745664739884, 
0.852601156069364, 0.867052023121387, 0.520231213872832, 0.563583815028902, 
0.794797687861272, 0.794797687861272, 0.679190751445087, 0.505780346820809, 
0.260115606936416, 0.823699421965318, 0.346820809248555, 0.173410404624277, 
0.534682080924855, 0.317919075144509, 1.11612443600095, 1.13195598828465, 
0.941977360880234, 0.862819599461727, 0.0949893137022085, 0.253304836539223, 
0.22164173197182, 0.277052164964775, 0.134568194411462, 0.316631045674028, 
0.387873030950685, 0.569935882213251, 0.609514762922505, 0.5620201060714, 
0.269136388822924, 0.324546821815879, 0.308715269532178, 0.44328346394364, 
0.213725955829969, 0.284967941106626, 0.34037837409958, 0.245389060397372, 
0.229557508113671, 0.269136388822924, 0.245389060397372, 0.213725955829969, 
0.229557508113671, 0.284967941106626, 0.205810179688118, 0.253304836539223
), Year = c(1989L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 
1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 
2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 
2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 2020L, 2021L, 2022L, 1989L, 1990L, 
1994L, 1995L, 1997L, 1998L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2005L, 2006L, 
2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 
2018L, 2019L, 2021L, 2022L, 1989L, 1990L, 1991L, 1994L, 1995L, 
1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 
2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2016L, 
2017L, 2019L, 2021L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2008L, 2009L, 
2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 
2019L, 2021L, 2022L, 1988L, 1989L, 1995L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 
2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 
2010L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 2019L, 
2021L, 1980L, 1982L, 1983L, 1985L, 1986L, 1987L, 1988L, 1989L, 
1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 
1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2006L, 2007L, 2010L, 
2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2019L, 2020L, 2021L, 1986L, 
1987L, 1989L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2005L, 
2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 1987L, 1988L, 1989L, 1998L, 
1999L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 
2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 
2018L, 2019L, 2021L, 2022L, 1983L, 1987L, 1989L, 1990L, 1992L, 
1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 
2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2012L, 
2013L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 2019L, 2021L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 37L, 38L, 
39L, 40L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 96L, 97L, 101L, 102L, 104L, 105L, 108L, 
109L, 110L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 
122L, 123L, 125L, 126L, 128L, 129L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 142L, 143L, 
145L, 146L, 147L, 149L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 156L, 
157L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 161L, 162L, 164L, 165L, 167L, 169L, 195L, 
196L, 197L, 198L, 200L, 201L, 202L, 203L, 204L, 205L, 206L, 207L, 
208L, 209L, 210L, 211L, 213L, 214L, 221L, 222L, 228L, 230L, 231L, 
232L, 234L, 235L, 236L, 237L, 238L, 239L, 240L, 241L, 242L, 243L, 
245L, 246L, 247L, 248L, 249L, 250L, 251L, 252L, 254L, 263L, 265L, 
266L, 268L, 269L, 270L, 271L, 272L, 273L, 274L, 275L, 276L, 277L, 
278L, 279L, 280L, 281L, 282L, 283L, 284L, 285L, 286L, 287L, 289L, 
290L, 293L, 296L, 297L, 298L, 299L, 300L, 302L, 303L, 304L, 352L, 
353L, 355L, 364L, 365L, 366L, 367L, 368L, 369L, 371L, 372L, 373L, 
374L, 375L, 376L, 434L, 435L, 436L, 445L, 446L, 448L, 449L, 450L, 
451L, 452L, 453L, 454L, 455L, 456L, 457L, 458L, 459L, 460L, 461L, 
462L, 463L, 464L, 465L, 466L, 468L, 469L, 481L, 485L, 487L, 488L, 
490L, 492L, 493L, 494L, 495L, 496L, 497L, 498L, 499L, 500L, 501L, 
502L, 503L, 504L, 505L, 506L, 507L, 508L, 510L, 511L, 513L, 514L, 
515L, 516L, 517L, 519L))
```

Data that does not work

```
dput(notworks)
structure(list(EST.1.100m = c(50.03436426, 29.6619718333333, 
21.3333333333333, 17.5644444466667, 10.9090909066667, 1.33333333333333, 
3.926589776, 9.74298464, 12.6666666666667, 25.6666666666667, 
18.73469388, 16.11965812, 28.6349206333333, 58.4074074066667, 
36.7659574466667, 30.1363636333333, 32.37777778, 10, 13.93939394, 
32.6210045666667, 46.7801418466667, 44.12658228, 36.9047619066667, 
37.5257731933333, 19.53488372, 23.8095238066667, 4.8, 1.10168078533333, 
12.6, 50.08695652, 7.33333333333333, 7.33333333333333, 18.5365853666667, 
20, 52.52252252, 10.2941176466667, 18.7659574466667, 15.97222222, 
2.35121559666667, 9.91256651333333, 7.06542329333333, 8.66666666666667, 
3.78126288866667, 2.66666666666667, 2.35121559666667, 9.33333333333333, 
14.6363636333333, 10.3703703733333, 19.76470588, 1.33333333333333, 
3.33333333333333, 2.66666666666667, 8.22925458666667, 16.6962962933333, 
10.98039216, 23.5294117666667, 3.54166666666667, 9.53333333333333, 
21.10638298, 21.3333333333333, 15.05376344, 29.7721519, 19.25, 
25.2470588266667, 29.5909090933333, 21.09722222, 26.57777778, 
10.98039216, 30.68992248, 22.2189054733333, 24.9263157866667, 
16.4833333333333, 19.0188679266667, 37.5, 20.73429952, 39.79288026, 
20.1165048533333, 30.3003663, 21.81818182, 21.3918128666667, 
19.6756756733333, 20.6666666666667, 2.836471968, 13.0888888866667, 
12.6666666666667, 8.15514054, 10, 4.41666666666667, 6.96, 8.5106383, 
21.3333333333333, 32.4133333333333, 14.875, 10.7916666666667, 
8.08080808, 10.2702702733333, 25.14285714, 7.56989247333333, 
14.9787234066667, 15.44827586, 19.1020408133333, 7.55555555333333, 
7.33333333333333, 7.98039216, 18.60465116, 16.1333333333333, 
2.66666666666667, 6.66666666666667, 4.66666666666667, 5.33333333333333, 
24, 20.6666666666667, 30.4411764733333, 23.2962962933333, 63.05084746, 
20.6666666666667, 58.5347985333333, 49.18996416, 35.4430379733333, 
48.32982456, 57.1358024666667, 26.1333333333333, 59.9925925933333, 
77.0833333333333, 65.3195876266667, 62.58064516, 52.5821596266667, 
105, 32.3037974666667, 17.90804598, 25.31073446, 9.52, 24.92307692, 
9.33333333333333, 20.3333333333333, 13, 11, 27.90277778, 15.3333333333333, 
25.1700680266667, 14.31884058, 16.6666666666667, 16, 41.95767196, 
24.5333333333333, 13.8461538466667, 13.0666666666667, 15.3333333333333, 
11.3333333333333, 20.5050505066667, 18.75, 9.33333333333333, 
14.71264368, 83.8666666666667, 50.9390681, 27.2333333333333, 
50.30420712, 57.11442786, 75.8137254666667, 46.8841607533333, 
64.5882352933333, 3.401360544, 62.84126984, 12.4, 57.92063492, 
1.50617283933333, 57.7073170733333, 5.33333333333333, 20.5333333333333, 
25.7627118666667, 23.4347826066667, 19.7727272733333, 16.1, 27.1515151533333, 
45.6038647333333, 3.33333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 5.33333333333333, 
6.588235294, 33.25170068, 32.3076923066667, 3.33333333333333, 
4.24036956666667, 6, 5.30975916533333, 9.62962962666667, 4.66666666666667, 
21.77777778, 11.6875, 3.33333333333333, 5.650301078, 12.5714285733333, 
1.33333333333333, 6, 3.33333333333333, 24.6153846133333, 15.3333333333333, 
1.33333333333333, 2.21329558933333, 36.8609271533333, 25.3255813933333, 
30.0487804866667, 4.925925926, 4.48697225266667, 2.66666666666667, 
10, 8.04597701333333, 11.3333333333333, 10, 12, 2.78260869533333, 
2.66666666666667, 8.28571428666667, 21.2105263133333, 8.35555555333333, 
27.3684210533333, 30.5217391333333, 17.9523809533333, 13.8730158733333, 
2.66666666666667, 24.48979592, 35.7894736866667, 0.666666666666667, 
16.6666666666667, 35.23497268, 5.33333333333333, 17.0542635666667, 
9.33333333333333, 6, 12.3529411733333, 1.33333333333333, 14.6031746, 
2.66666666666667, 7.33333333333333, 31.1538461533333, 13.2173913066667, 
7.43589743333333, 14.6666666666667, 15.3333333333333, 20.8333333333333, 
25.1234567933333, 25.81560284, 15.3333333333333, 19.54285714, 
10.7466666666667, 9.33333333333333, 8, 16, 19.9689922466667, 
10, 15.12, 2.19047619066667, 12.0888888866667, 19.3333333333333, 
2.823529412, 13.3333333333333, 9.16594128, 19.8333333333333, 
22.6285714266667, 10.9090909066667, 16.2095238066667, 29.2307692333333, 
15.5833333333333, 14.98245614, 40.18079096, 36.8547008533333, 
31.9444444466667, 9.89333333333333, 4.336925954, 69.5338346, 
13.87755102, 14.9333333333333, 26.08955224, 47.37078652, 22.8194444466667, 
25.5163398666667, 3.43434343466667, 11.6097561, 15.5555555533333, 
10.4347826066667, 18.12121212, 17.3333333333333, 16.7272727266667, 
51.24919094, 19.1489361733333, 27.9545454533333, 9.82222222, 
13.5714285733333, 9.62962962666667, 6.02898550733333, 20.45410628, 
3.97987201733333, 39.3734939733333, 2.73873873866667, 8.04828215333333, 
20.8627451, 22.5333333333333, 34.5570776266667, 15.05376344, 
9.04901960666667, 35.4020618533333, 60.5984252, 58.4806201533333, 
40.3045267466667, 2.89493785933333, 40.0650406533333, 9.33333333333333, 
24.1935483866667), Redds.100m = c(0.328478152507479, 0.342164742195291, 
0.437970870009972, 0.218985435004986, 0.0273731793756233, 0.150552486565928, 
0.191612255629363, 0.0821195381268698, 0.177925665941551, 0.410597690634349, 
0.465344049385595, 0.437970870009972, 0.301104973131856, 0.16423907625374, 
0.16423907625374, 0.150552486565928, 0.205298845317174, 0.50640381844903, 
0.547463587512465, 0.287418383444044, 0.314791562819667, 0.109492717502493, 
0.123179307190305, 0.0821195381268698, 0.109492717502493, 0.287418383444044, 
0.0547463587512465, 0.218985435004986, 0.218985435004986, 0.0547463587512465, 
0.191612255629363, 0.396911100946537, 0.863015604357746, 0.500549050527492, 
0.586850610963267, 0.172603120871549, 0.103561872522929, 0.224384057133014, 
0.241644369220169, 0.120822184610084, 0.0517809362614647, 0, 
0, 0.0517809362614647, 0.0517809362614647, 0.0690412483486196, 
0.0690412483486196, 0.0517809362614647, 0, 0.0690412483486196, 
0.103561872522929, 0.189863432958704, 0.396987178004563, 0.0690412483486196, 
0.155342808784394, 0.0690412483486196, 0.0863015604357746, 0.138082496697239, 
0.0863015604357746, 0.466028426353183, 3.39926568550944, 2.48548458725422, 
3.56374628319538, 2.86927264852141, 3.39926568550944, 4.73338608896207, 
3.01547762424225, 2.77789453869589, 3.07030449013756, 2.90582389245162, 
3.25306070978861, 3.41754130747455, 3.19823384389329, 2.44893334332401, 
2.11997214795212, 1.66308159882451, 1.55342786703388, 1.53515224506878, 
1.37067164738284, 1.40722289131305, 0.731024878604181, 0.511717415022927, 
0.639646768778658, 0.603095524848449, 0.440137939230155, 0.34952130468277, 
0.401302238709847, 0.854385411446771, 0.414247472216616, 1.10034484807539, 
0.919111578980617, 0.595480741311386, 1.178016249116, 0.69904260936554, 
1.03561868054154, 0.86733064495354, 0.841440177940002, 0.802604477419694, 
0.970892513007694, 0.893221111967079, 0.932056812487387, 0.737878309885848, 
0.168288035588, 0.34952130468277, 0.245959436628616, 0.478973639750462, 
0.168288035588, 0.297740370655693, 0.323630837669231, 0.103561868054154, 
0.257641729473153, 0.257641729473153, 0.121243166810896, 0.242486333621791, 
0.409195687986772, 0.363729500432687, 0.621371229905839, 0.500128063094944, 
0.681992813311287, 0.409195687986772, 0.560749646500392, 0.439506479689496, 
0.575905042351754, 0.363729500432687, 0.46981727139222, 0.424351083838134, 
0.212175541919067, 0.454661875540858, 0.670915730816636, 0.867029559824575, 
1.75470268059735, 1.9611382900794, 1.45537104684839, 1.39344036400378, 
1.36247502258148, 1.05282160835841, 0.949603803617392, 1.20764831546994, 
0.774133535557656, 1.40376214447788, 1.40376214447788, 0.949603803617392, 
1.03217804741021, 0.608985047972023, 0.815420657454065, 0.433514779912288, 
0.9908909255138, 1.20764831546994, 0.712202852713044, 0.639950389394329, 
0.660593950342533, 0.268366292326654, 0.309653414223063, 0.533824052873351, 
0.612118247294775, 0.47688282056686, 0.704647749792823, 0.37011800999219, 
0.348765047877256, 0.355882701915567, 0.448412204413615, 0.170823696919472, 
0.32029443172401, 0.121000118651293, 0.0996471565363588, 0.149470734804538, 
0.199294313072718, 0.0640588863448021, 0.277588507494142, 0.249117891340897, 
0.21352962114934, 0.355882701915567, 0.284706161532454, 0.21352962114934, 
0.15658838884285, 0.0711765403831134, 0.0782941944214248, 0.149470734804538, 
0.306059123647388, 0.384353318068812, 0.37011800999219, 0.384353318068812, 
0.448412204413615, 0.227764929225963, 0.284706161532454, 0.277588507494142, 
0.149470734804538, 0.232166955901328, 0.104074842300595, 0.0320230284001831, 
0.0240172713001374, 0.0480345426002747, 0.0320230284001831, 0.0240172713001374, 
0.0720518139004121, 0.0720518139004121, 0.0480345426002747, 0, 
0.0480345426002747, 0.510716028127402, 0.638395035159252, 0.297917683074318, 
0.31210423941119, 0.368850464758679, 0.482342915453657, 0.411410133769296, 
0.297917683074318, 0.297917683074318, 0.226984901389956, 0.43978324644304, 
0.411410133769296, 0.62420847882238, 0.482342915453657, 0.453969802779913, 
0.759453644445437, 0.207123721212392, 0.184109974411015, 0.115068734006884, 
0.0920549872055075, 0.0230137468013769, 0.0230137468013769, 0.0690412404041306, 
0.0460274936027537, 0.0460274936027537, 0.43726118922616, 0.0460274936027537, 
0.230137468013769, 0.207123721212392, 0.0920549872055075, 0.0230137468013769, 
0.184109974411015, 0.0460274936027537, 0.322192455219276, 0.36821994882203, 
0.924831568663181, 0.13005443934326, 0.968183048444267, 2.03751954971107, 
0.85257910236137, 1.64735623168129, 1.76296017776419, 1.22829192713079, 
1.35834636647405, 1.48840080581731, 1.63290573842093, 1.77741067102455, 
0.85257910236137, 0.867029595621732, 0.520217757373039, 0.563569237154126, 
0.794777129319921, 0.794777129319921, 0.679173183237023, 0.505767264112677, 
0.260108878686519, 0.823678115840645, 0.346811838248693, 0.173405919124346, 
0.534668250633401, 0.317910851727968, 1.1160935143885, 1.13192462806777, 
0.941951263916538, 0.862795695520191, 0.0949866820756173, 0.253297818868313, 
0.221635591509774, 0.277044489387217, 0.134564466273791, 0.316622273585391, 
0.387862285142104, 0.569920092453704, 0.609497876651878, 0.562004535614069, 
0.269128932547582, 0.324537830425026, 0.308706716745756, 0.443271183019547, 
0.213720034670139, 0.284960046226852, 0.340368944104295, 0.245382262028678, 
0.229551148349409, 0.269128932547582, 0.245382262028678, 0.213720034670139, 
0.229551148349409, 0.284960046226852, 0.205804477830504, 0.253297818868313, 
0.528165513401734, 0.636905472043267, 0.217479917283067, 0.0466028394178, 
0.1398085182534, 0.0776713990296667, 0.155342798059333, 0.0776713990296667, 
0.730111150878867, 0.621371192237334, 0.481562673983934, 0.217479917283067, 
0.403891274954267, 0.2796170365068, 0.3262198759246, 0.264082756700867, 
0.217479917283067, 0.233014197089), Year = c(1989L, 1990L, 1991L, 
1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 
2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 
2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 2020L, 
2021L, 2022L, 1989L, 1990L, 1991L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1998L, 
1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2007L, 2008L, 
2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2017L, 2018L, 
2019L, 2021L, 2022L, 1989L, 1990L, 1994L, 1995L, 1997L, 1998L, 
2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 
2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2018L, 2019L, 2021L, 2022L, 
1989L, 1990L, 1991L, 1994L, 1995L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2001L, 
2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 
2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2016L, 2017L, 2019L, 2021L, 2003L, 
2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 
2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 2019L, 2021L, 2022L, 1988L, 
1989L, 1995L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 
2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 
2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 2019L, 2021L, 1980L, 1982L, 1983L, 
1985L, 1986L, 1987L, 1988L, 1989L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 
1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 
2003L, 2004L, 2006L, 2007L, 2010L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 
2017L, 2019L, 2020L, 2021L, 1989L, 1990L, 1992L, 2000L, 2007L, 
2008L, 2009L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2018L, 2019L, 1986L, 1987L, 
1989L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2005L, 2006L, 
2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 1989L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1997L, 
2000L, 2003L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 
2014L, 2015L, 2017L, 2018L, 2021L, 2022L, 1987L, 1988L, 1989L, 
1998L, 1999L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 
2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 
2017L, 2018L, 2019L, 2021L, 2022L, 1983L, 1987L, 1989L, 1990L, 
1992L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 
2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 
2012L, 2013L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 2019L, 2021L, 1995L, 
1996L, 1997L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 
2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2017L, 2018L, 2020L, 2021L, 2022L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 37L, 38L, 
39L, 40L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 64L, 65L, 
66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 
80L, 81L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 87L, 88L, 96L, 97L, 101L, 102L, 104L, 
105L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 119L, 
120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 125L, 126L, 128L, 129L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 
142L, 143L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 149L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 
155L, 156L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 161L, 162L, 164L, 165L, 167L, 
169L, 195L, 196L, 197L, 198L, 200L, 201L, 202L, 203L, 204L, 205L, 
206L, 207L, 208L, 209L, 210L, 211L, 213L, 214L, 221L, 222L, 228L, 
230L, 231L, 232L, 234L, 235L, 236L, 237L, 238L, 239L, 240L, 241L, 
242L, 243L, 245L, 246L, 247L, 248L, 249L, 250L, 251L, 252L, 254L, 
263L, 265L, 266L, 268L, 269L, 270L, 271L, 272L, 273L, 274L, 275L, 
276L, 277L, 278L, 279L, 280L, 281L, 282L, 283L, 284L, 285L, 286L, 
287L, 289L, 290L, 293L, 296L, 297L, 298L, 299L, 300L, 302L, 303L, 
304L, 313L, 314L, 316L, 324L, 331L, 332L, 333L, 335L, 336L, 337L, 
341L, 342L, 352L, 353L, 355L, 364L, 365L, 366L, 367L, 368L, 369L, 
371L, 372L, 373L, 374L, 375L, 376L, 395L, 396L, 397L, 398L, 403L, 
406L, 409L, 413L, 414L, 415L, 416L, 417L, 418L, 419L, 420L, 421L, 
423L, 424L, 427L, 428L, 434L, 435L, 436L, 445L, 446L, 448L, 449L, 
450L, 451L, 452L, 453L, 454L, 455L, 456L, 457L, 458L, 459L, 460L, 
461L, 462L, 463L, 464L, 465L, 466L, 468L, 469L, 481L, 485L, 487L, 
488L, 490L, 492L, 493L, 494L, 495L, 496L, 497L, 498L, 499L, 500L, 
501L, 502L, 503L, 504L, 505L, 506L, 507L, 508L, 510L, 511L, 513L, 
514L, 515L, 516L, 517L, 519L, 523L, 524L, 525L, 528L, 529L, 530L, 
531L, 533L, 534L, 535L, 536L, 537L, 538L, 545L, 546L, 548L, 549L, 
550L))
```

Comment: `r[43]` refers to the 43rd element of your vector `R`, which forms part of your model.  What is the value of `R[43]` in both vectors?  What are the values of the predictors in row `43` of both data sets?  I suspect `R[43]` might be negative/missing/zero in the data set that errors.

Comment: Yes!! That was it! There were 0 values present. So, obviously I named a vector R...if I get a different error in a different model with a different named parent error, will it always be related to the predictors in the observed dataset? Or can you get this error related to non-observed data parts of the model?